# Map Reduce kind of query with need to correlate with previous row

Tags: mongodb

I have following schema:

- Client ID
- Location Name
- Time of Visit
- Purchases made // This is a list

Since this is an unstructured data, Flat DB like MongoDB will be natural fit. We are using MongoDB.

This data stores the client visit information at various locations. Suppose I want to find out the number of repeat visits on a particular day. The logic for Repeat visit is simple: If a person has visited a store today had visited the same store earlier, then he's a repeat visitor at that store.

I've a logic using which I could find out the number of repeat visitors:

Query: Select * From Schema order by Location ID ASC , Client ID ASC, 'Time of Visit' ASC

Once the data for this above query is sorted, we can compare 'Time of Visit' previous and next rows if LocationID and Client ID match. If the difference if of > 1 day, its a repeat visit.

Since this data is very huge, join type of query would be highly inefficient (Even if it were possible in MongoDB).

Now I understand that there is map reduce framework in MongoDB. However, is it possible to perform comparison between previous and current record, and do some computation based on that, after which map/reduce could be triggered?

Example :

- Customer A visits store B on day 1        // No repeat visit
- Customer A visits store B again on day 1  // Still no repeat visit
- Customer A visits store B on day 2        // Repeat visit for this customer A on day 2
- Customer A visits store B on day 2        // Already counted as repeat visit on day 2
- Customer A visits store B on day 3        // Repeat visit for this customer on day 3
- Customer C visits store B on day 2        // First visit for customer C, not a repeat visit
- Customer C visits store B again on day 2  // First day of visit, not a repeat visit
- Customer C visits store B on day 3        // Repeat Visit on day 3
- Customer C visits store B on day 4        // Repeat Visit on day 4
- Customer D visits store B on day 5        // First visit, not a repeat visit

Final output of repeat visits:

- Store B, Day 1 : 0 Repeat Visits
- Store B, Day 2 : 2 Repeat Visits
- Store B, Day 3 : 2 Repeat Visits
- Store B, Day 4 : 1 Repeat Visits
- Store B, Day 5 : 0 Repeat Visits

Comment: Since your question is abstract, and since you did figure out the logic, here is a resource that might be helpful: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/sql-aggregation-comparison/. Map-Reduce may not be required in all cases. There are a lot of aggregation functions(or may be, selectors) that MongoDB provides that may be useful in your case.

Comment: @Kashyap: I don't think aggregation would help us achieve what we're trying to get efficiently. I hope you see what I mean, since join is obviously not desired for a database of millions or rows size.

Comment: You can do this with aggregation framework - it would be faster than map reduce too.

Comment: since you only described one table, I don't quite understand what join you are referring to. you can't do a 'select' in SQL to calculate the information you are looking for (all the work would then be done on the client, which is very sub-optimal).  I assume your time of visit holds full date-time.  It's also unclear whether you are limiting your query to a particular day and asking how many locations had repeat visits or if you want to know for all days by day how many total or by location repeat visits there were.

Comment: @AsyaKamsky: I want to find the repeat visits per location, per day. So if I have data for 2 stores for 10 days, the result set will have 20 rows.

Comment: @AsyaKamsky: You are correct, I don't want to do the processing in the application. If there's any mechanism using which I could do it in the database, be it aggregation framework or map reduce framework, I am fine with it. If I had to compare how to do this is postgres, then a procedure would have done the trick, since I could compare the previous and current rows by using PLpgSQL procedure. However, since my requirement is that of storing an unstructured data, relational DB is not a good fit. Is there any equivalent or alternative which allows me to do that in MongoDB or other NOSQL DB?

Comment: result set should not have 20 rows - you only want to know about repeat visits, right?  Not all visits?  For each day you will only have one or two records if one or both stores had repeat visits, yes?

Comment: see my answer.  I showed a couple of different ways to aggregate, you can extend to output the exact grouping you want in the result.

Comment: @AsyaKamsky, I want to find repeat visits at per location level, per day. If a person went to store A on day 1, and to store B on day 2, that won't be counted as a repeat visit.

Comment: That's what my answer shows how to do.  Aggregate by customer, by location, by day.  Filter and otherwise process as needed.

Comment: @AsyaKamsy: My definition of repeat visit is a bit different. Let me again try to define the repeat visit as required by me. If a customer A visits location B on Day N, then he's not contributed to repeat visit on Day N for location B if he'd NOT visited the same location B before Day N. If he's visited same location on a previous date, then he's a repeat visit for this date, but it doesn't matter how many times he's made visits for this date. Contribution to repeat visits by a customer for a day for a location cannot be more than one. That's the reason aggregation is not the correct option.

Comment: @AsyaKamsky: Please see my edit in the question, which now includes an example. It should clarify the definition of repeat visits hopefully.

Comment: I see - its still simple with aggregation, I will update my answer later today to clarify

Comment: Undated the answer - it's still aggregation - first by customer, by store by day and then just by customer, by store, which gives you count of days for each customer-store combination.

Comment: @AsyaKamsy: Please refer the example that I've added in my question. Your answer is not still the repeat visit logic that I'm looking for. I'm looking at output of format (Day, Location, # Repeat Visits). What you've mentioned is totally different of format (ClientID, Location, # Days with Repeat Visit)

Answer (score 0):

If you were doing this in relational database you would not be comparing visits row by row, instead you would use an aggregation query to find repeat visits (using SELECT ... GROUP BY) so you should do it the same way in MongoDB.

First you need to aggregate visits per customer per store per day:

```
group1 = { "$group" : {
        "_id" : {
            "c" : "$clientId",
            "l" : "$location",
            "day" : {
                "y" : {
                    "$year" : "$tov"
                },
                "m" : {
                    "$month" : "$tov"
                },
                "d" : {
                    "$dayOfMonth" : "$tov"
                }
            }
        },
        "visits" : {
            "$sum" : 1
        }
    }
};
```

*EDIT* since you want only repeat DAYS next you would group by customer, by store and count how many different DAYS there were for visits by that customer to that store:

```
group2 = {"$group" : 
    {"_id" : {
        "c" : "$_id.c",
        "s" : "$_id.l"
    },
    "totalDays" : {
        "$sum" : 1
    }
} };
```

Then you want to only include the records from above where there were more than one visit by the same customer to the same store across multiple days:

```
match = { "$match" : { "totalDays" : { "$gt" : 1 } } };
```

Here's a sample data set and the result of this aggregations using the above pipeline operations:

```
> db.visits.find({},{_id:0,purchases:0}).sort({location:1, clientId:1, tov:1})
{ "clientId" : 1, "location" : "l1", "tov" : ISODate("2013-01-01T20:00:00Z") }
{ "clientId" : 1, "location" : "l1", "tov" : ISODate("2013-01-01T21:00:00Z") }
{ "clientId" : 1, "location" : "l1", "tov" : ISODate("2013-01-03T20:00:00Z") }
{ "clientId" : 2, "location" : "l1", "tov" : ISODate("2013-01-01T21:00:00Z") }
{ "clientId" : 3, "location" : "l1", "tov" : ISODate("2013-01-01T21:00:00Z") }
{ "clientId" : 3, "location" : "l1", "tov" : ISODate("2013-01-02T21:00:00Z") }
{ "clientId" : 1, "location" : "l2", "tov" : ISODate("2013-01-01T23:00:00Z") }
{ "clientId" : 3, "location" : "l2", "tov" : ISODate("2013-01-02T21:00:00Z") }
{ "clientId" : 3, "location" : "l2", "tov" : ISODate("2013-01-02T21:00:00Z") }
{ "clientId" : 1, "location" : "l3", "tov" : ISODate("2013-01-03T20:00:00Z") }
{ "clientId" : 2, "location" : "l3", "tov" : ISODate("2013-01-04T20:00:00Z") }
{ "clientId" : 4, "location" : "l3", "tov" : ISODate("2013-01-04T20:00:00Z") }
{ "clientId" : 4, "location" : "l3", "tov" : ISODate("2013-01-04T21:00:00Z") }
{ "clientId" : 4, "location" : "l3", "tov" : ISODate("2013-01-04T22:00:00Z") }

> db.visits.aggregate(group1, group2, match)
{
    "result" : [
    {
        "_id" : {
            "c" : 3,
            "s" : "l1"
        },
        "totalDays" : 2
    },
    {
        "_id" : {
            "c" : 1,
            "s" : "l1"
        },
        "totalDays" : 2
    }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

Comment: A repeat visit is defined at a particular location per day. So if a person comes to a store A on day 1, and comes again on day 1, it wont be counted as a repeat visit. On the contrary, if he comes again on day 2, it would be counted as a repeat visit. The above explanation does not compare the previous rows with current rows. I hope you see that the definition of repeat visit that you've used is different than the one you've used. Also, if a person visits store A on day 1, and store 2 on day 2, it wont be counted as a repeat visit.

Comment: I don't think you understand how aggregation works. This is not about comparing rows.  Once you GROUP all visits for customer A to location B on Day N all you need to know is that if it's greater than ONE then there was repeat visit.  That's why after grouping by customer/location/day I have a $match step to only match groupings where number of visits is > 1

Comment: @AsyaKamsy: My definition of repeat visit is a bit different. Let me again try to define the repeat visit as required by me. If a customer A visits location B on Day N, then he's not contributed to repeat visit on Day N for location B if he'd NOT visited the same location B before Day N. Example below:

(a)Customer A  Location B   Day 1:  No repeat visit
(b)Customer A  Location B   Day 1:  Still No repeat visit
(c)Customer A  Location B   Day 2:  1 repeat visit on Day 2
(d)Customer A  Location B   Day 2:  Still 1 repeat visit on Day 2
(e)Customer A  Location B   Day 3:  1 repeat visit on Day 3

Comment: @AsyaKamsy, see the edit I made in my question which now has an example added to it.

Comment: @AsyaKamsy: Please refer the example that I've added in my question. Your answer is not still the repeat visit logic that I'm looking for. I'm looking at output of format (Day, Location, # Repeat Visits). What you've mentioned is totally different of format (ClientID, Location, # Days with Repeat Visit)

Comment: I showed you how to use aggregation framework to get the information you need - can't you figure out yourself how to put it in the right format?